# Bash: why does 'return 0' in parenthesis doesn't exit the function

Tags: bash, shell

In the following bash code example. I expect `return 0` to exit the function when calling the function with `0`. However, the function continues forward.

```
ignoringReturnStatement(){
  local seconds="$1"
  [[ "$seconds" -eq "0" ]] && (echo "equals 0" && return 0 )

  echo "Didn't exit with 'return 0'"
  return 1
}
ignoringReturnStatement 0 && echo "Return code truthy" || echo "Return code falsy"
```

Output

```
equals 0
Didn't exit with 'return 0'
Return code falsy
```

Why in the world is `return 0` ignored? Does it somehow get scoped down the just parentheses () that its in? (I am used to bash not doing much scoping down so that would be super surprising)

I could refactor this code to work as expected using more verbose `if syntax`:

```
respectingReturnStatement(){
  local seconds="$1"
  if [[ "$seconds" -eq "0" ]]; then
     echo "equals 0"
     return 0
  fi

  echo "Didn't exit with 'return 0'"
  return 1
}
respectingReturnStatement 0 && echo "Return code truthy" || echo "Return code falsy"
```

But why does `&& (... return 0)` syntax not work here?

Comment: It's not being ignored; it's executing in a subshell.  It's not immediately obvious to me if it *fails*, because it's not being used in a function in that shell, or if it "returns" from that subshell to the function.

Answer (score 3):

It's not being ignored; it's executing in a subshell. It's not immediately obvious to me if it *fails*, because it's not being used in a function in that shell, or if it "returns" from that subshell to the function.

To fix this, use `{...}`, not `(...)`, so that `return` executes in the same shell as the rest of the function.

```
foo (){
  local seconds="$1"
  [[ "$seconds" -eq "0" ]] && { echo "equals 0"; return 0; }

  echo "Didn't exit with 'return 0'"
  return 1
}
```

There's little reason to use `&&` over `;`, since you want to return even if, for some rare reason, `echo` fails.